# php mcrypt_encrypt result is not equal to java gnu-crypto

Tags: java, php, encryption

PHP version:

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, "11111111111111111111111111111111", "11111111111111111111111111111111", MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, "11111111111111111111111111111111")
//byte array result:197 225 204 225 20 63 221 2 108 243 172 211 201 17 108 221 53 236 203 147 221 148 73 227 59 26 253 96 240 102 230 118
```

Java version:

```
byte[] pt = "11111111111111111111111111111111".getBytes();
byte[] ct = new byte[32];

IMode mode = ModeFactory.getInstance("CFB", "Rijndael", 32);
Map attributes = new HashMap();
attributes.put(IMode.KEY_MATERIAL, "11111111111111111111111111111111".getBytes());
attributes.put(IMode.CIPHER_BLOCK_SIZE, new Integer(32));
attributes.put(IMode.STATE, new Integer(IMode.ENCRYPTION));
attributes.put(IMode.IV, "11111111111111111111111111111111".getBytes());
mode.init(attributes);
mode.update(pt, 0, ct, 0);
//byte array result: -59 39 -23 -128 94 -42 97 -120 122 -3 -34 -13 70 43 -16 -41 -104 40 -11 83 36 56 -55 66 115 -78 97 -104 58 -38 74 -110
```

PHP mcrypt_encrypt result is not equal to java gnu-crypto.

This is really odd. I checked that all the key size, block size, vi size are same.

Comment: Could you try and print all input/output as hexadecimals? +1 as I don't know this Java/GNU API. You could try the more common lightweight Bouncy Castle API if this one does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try using MCRYPT_MODE_ECB without the iv. also please make sure your block size is 16.

Comment: No. You cannot change any encryption mode, algorithm and key size in Java version and PHP version

Comment: but are you using the 32 block size on php as well? please pad your input so it get strict size of 32, because i see you are using 32 in java.

Comment: Solved! The key size in php is 16 bytes not 32 bytes